# Eagle PCB design issue

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, copper-pour

I have finished the schematic layout for my design which contains transformer. I also found the optimized design 100%, but the transformer background should be black while I'm having only portion of it black, any idea on how to do it?

[image]

Comment: I recommend avoiding right-angles whenever possible in PCB design. Having sharp corners makes it much easier for the traces to peel up. Use 45 degree angles instead of 90-degree corners

Comment: @derstrom8 how can I do it could you give me a hint please? this my first experience using eagle for PCB.

Comment: How can you change the corners, or how can you change the polygon pour? When you created the polygon, you had to first draw the outline. All you have to do is click the outside edge of the pour and it should highlight the edges of the whole polygon. You can then drag the sides to change its shape

Comment: As for making 45-degree corners, I believe the spacebar changes the trace style in Eagle. This is from memory though, I've been using Altium for a while.

Comment: @derstrom8: a right-click will change the style as well and is more comfortable as you're already drawing the tracks with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks @sweber, you're right--THAT'S how I always did it. I remember now!

Comment: @derstrom8 thanks everyone for your help, problem is solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your polygon pour is filling in (showing as blue). To make your "background black" under the transformer, you need to change the shape of your polygon. When you created the polygon, you had to first draw the outline. All you have to do is click the outside edge of the pour and it should highlight the edges of the whole polygon. You can then drag the sides to change its shape.

Not sure why you don't want the pour under the transformer though. Assuming it's insulated with solder mask and your transformer is in a protective case, having the polygon pour completely shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Or, rather than drawing the polygon a funny shape, you can also draw a box or polygon on the bRestrict layer. This will cause the polygon to be removed anywhere that it crosses the restrict.

Comment: Good call Tom! Forgot how that was done in Eagle

Answer (score 5):

The blue under the transformer is a polygon (copper pour) in the bottom layer.  You can change the polygon's geometry by dragging its corners.  After you change the shape, the fill will disappear, and dotted line will show around the polygon.  Click `Ratsnest` on the toolbar, and the polygon will fill again.

[How to work with polygons work in Eagle](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Eagle_Polygons)
[Adding copper pour](https://lucidar.me/en/eagle/adding-copper-pour-in-eagle/) - introductory tutorial